# Why does prepend() javascript method not work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox, dom-manipulation

I'm practicing with DOM manipulation in JavaScript following a course.

I wriote the same code as the guy of the course but it doesn't work. The code should create an html element and add it to the DOM and it does, but the element is not showing in the page. Besides, if I open the inspector tool the element is there but is greyed out like when you put `display:none` ... it's invisible...
[image]

```js
const header = document.querySelector('.header');
const message = document.createElement('div');
message.classList.add('cookie-message');
message.innerHTML =
  'We use cookies for improved functionality and analytics. <button class="btn btn--close-cookie">Got it!</button>';
header.prepend(message);
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 3em;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.cookie-message {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
    
    </header>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I am using FireFox as browser and I saw on MDN documentation about `Element.prepend()` that it is fully supported by FireFox but for me is not working...

Then I tried on Chrome and it works.

[image]

Someone can help me out? Am I missing something?

Comment: _"Am I missing something?"_ - An actual [mcve] because your snippet works as expected.

Comment: Your screenshot would have been more useful if the problematic element were selected (the `div`). What is the CSS that is applied to that item (computed!)? I am running this on FF and there is no problem. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: I was actually able to reproduce the problem, though I can't explain it: it seems to come from the class name, of all things: if you change `'cookie-message'`  to something like `'cookie-messag'` or `'cookie-messagee'`, it seems to go away....

Comment: @trincot yes my bad, updated the screenshot

Comment: @JackFleeting i tried what you said and changing the class name to 'cookie-messag' it works. But I still don't understand why now it works and befor eit didn't...

Comment: @Jay Yes, it's only a problem with Firefox (tried on two different computers); no issue with Edge. I would really like someone smarter to explain this, so it's really a pity the question was closed.

Comment: @JackFleeting It got closed because the code in the question does not reproduce the problem... Asking the same question again just without the image won't change anything and should also be closed (and in this case as a dupe of this question). The only real solution is to modify the question so it actually contains a [mcve]...

Comment: @Andreas The example is perfectly reproducible if you run it in Firefox (see the link in my previous comment). I spent quite a lot of time trying to figure it out - unsuccessfuly, so far. Frankly, if OP doesn't post a clearer, more streamlined version of the question (basically, "what does Firefox have against this particular class name?") I was thinking about posting it myself - I'm that bothered about it. Obviously, you can feel free to vote to close it as well...

Comment: @JackFleeting, the issue is that _this question_ should be modified and reopened instead of being reposted. See [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/248627), in particular: "**Do not post your question a second time,** as it will be closed as a duplicate of your first question, and may attract downvotes. Also, **do not delete your question and re-ask it,** as your previous question will be undeleted and your new one closed as a duplicate." It's in the reopen queue, and I just cast a reopen vote. Be patient.

Comment: (Though the relevant details from comments should also be edited into the question. _All_ relevant information should be in the question itself. I agree that a slimmed down version that points to the class name as an issue would be much clearer.)

Comment: @Chris Yes, you're probably right - patience is in order here. OP does have some work to do in order to tighten and focus the question. Let's hope he's up to the challenge because, I believe, the issue it raises is worth a serious examination by people who know what they're doing.

Comment: Are you certain it isn't a browser extension that hides cookie messages or similar? Ad block has a habit of hiding any divs with classnames along the lines of "advert" or "ad" for example. (I can see the example just fine)

Comment: @Djave That may well be the case; I'll try to disable some extensions to see if that changes the outcome. But, even if that's the case, isn't this too simple a filter for Ad Block - just changing or adding one character and the filter is bypassed?